# Word to describe the disappointment you feel when a previously admired author, artist or actor has questionable views

Tags: single-word-requests

There have been a number of authors, artists, actors, producers and directors I have previous enjoyed reading or watching; but (not naming names here) we then learn that they're physically abusive, racist, transphobic, homophobic, misogynist or otherwise objectionable.

I have a sense of disappointment in those people, and subsequently have trouble enjoying anything they have been involved in.  Is there a word for this sense of disappointment, as in:

> I feel ____ after discovering that (insert name) has offensive views about (insert topic).

Comment: Compare [milkshake duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milkshake_Duck).

Comment: When used as a verb, which it is, that's a great phrase, @StuartF to describe OP's feeling.  If this weren't a single word request, I would suggest [problematic fav](https://www.michigandaily.com/arts/a-problem-with-problematic-faves/) as well. There are [entire lists of them](https://lifehacker.com/the-your-fave-is-problematic-reading-list-1819283807)!

Comment: Thanks for those links.  "Betrayed", "disillusioned" and "disenchanted" are all perfectly valid words, but don't quite encompass what I meant; there may not be a single word that fits this bill.

Answer (score 1):

Betrayed: having one’s hopes or expectations disappointed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Two words that spring to mind are: **disillusioned** and **disenchanted**.

Here's *Cambridge Dictionary* defining the words:

**disillusioned**

> disappointed and unhappy because of discovering the truth about something or someone that you liked or respected

*He's become a disillusioned man.*

*All the other teachers are thoroughly disillusioned with their colleague.*

**disenchanted**

> no longer believing in the value of something, especially having learned of the problems with it

*Many voters have become disenchanted with the president.*

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there might be something a bit more specific, but this may be as close as I can get.